# Accessing dynamically allocated nested struct in C

Tags: c, struct, nested, dynamic-arrays, dereference

The structs are as follows, inner structs are inside outer structs. Both structs are dynamically allocated. The problem arises when I try to access an inner struct by means of a reference to change the address value.

For example:

```
typedef struct{
    char address[32];
}inner;

typedef struct{
    struct inner innerStruct;
}outer;

main(){

    int i = 0;
    outer* outerArray;
    outer* outerReference;
    inner* innerReference;

    /* create 20 outer structs */
    outerArray = malloc(20 * sizeof(outerArray*));

    /* for each outer struct, dynamically allocate 10 inner structs */

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        outerReference = outerArray + i;
        outerReference->innerStruct = malloc(10 * sizeof(outerReference->innerStruct);
    }

}
```

How can I access `outerArray[3][innerStruct[4]`, the 4th outer struct's 5th inner struct and change its address value?

Comment: That code doesn't compile (for a multitude of reasons).  You seem to be conflating pointers with object instances, among other things.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This seems to be a perfectly legitimate question from someone learning to navigate the intricacies of structures, pointers and memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `innerStruct`  as an `inner *`, rather than a `struct inner` if you want to use `malloc()`.

As you've declared it, the memory for `inner` is allocated when you create an `outer`.

Note also that, since you've used `typedef`, you don't need the `struct` keyword when you declare a variable of that type.

Here's a corrected version of your code that compiles and runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  char address[32];  // 32 chars are allocated when an inner is created
} inner;

typedef struct {
  inner innerStruct;  // innerStruct is allocated when an outer is created
} outer;

typedef struct {
  inner *innerStruct;  // innerStruct must be allocated explicitly
} outer2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  outer  *outerArray;
  outer2 *outer2Array;

  outer  *outerReference;
  outer2 *outer2Reference;

  /* create 20 outer structs (should check for out-of-mem error) */
  outerArray = malloc(20 * sizeof(outer));

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    outerReference = outerArray + i; // ptr to i'th outer
    // Note: innerStruct.address bcz it's a structure
    sprintf(outerReference->innerStruct.address, "outer struct %d", i);
  }

  /* create 20 outer2 structs */
  outer2Array = malloc(20 * sizeof(outer2));

  /* for each outer struct, dynamically allocate 10 inner structs */
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    outer2Reference = outer2Array + i;
    outer2Reference->innerStruct = malloc(sizeof(inner));
    // Note: innerStruct->address bcz it's a pointer
    sprintf(outer2Reference->innerStruct->address, "outer2 struct %d", i);
  }

  /* print all the data and free malloc'ed memory */
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("outer: %-20s, outer2: %-20s\n",
      outerArray[i].innerStruct.address,
      outer2Array[i].innerStruct->address);
      free(outer2Array[i].innerStruct);
  }
  free(outer2Array);
  free(outerArray);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: please god no `void main` it's so bad for many reasons. http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284376&answer=1044841143

Comment: @lukecampbell: Good catch, thank you.  Corrected, with another good reference: http://users.aber.ac.uk/auj/voidmain.cgi

Comment: I feel like this will print out the first inner struct's addresses of each outer struct. Wouldn't there be 2 for loops? The first looping through the outer structs and the nested one looping through each outer struct's inner structs?

Comment: @user1177044 You could do that if you allocated more than one inner struct to each outer struct.  There are several different reasons for using a pointer instead of an object.  You may want an array, or you may just want to allocate the memory dynamically to a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Prints member `address` of 5th inner strucuture of 4th outer structure, copies data into it and prints it again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char address[32];
}inner;

typedef struct{
    inner* innerStruct;
}outer;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    outer* outerArray;
    outer* outerReference;
    /* inner* innerReference; */ /* unused */

    /* create 20 outer structs */
    outerArray = malloc(20 * sizeof(*outerArray));

    /* for each outer struct, dynamically allocate 10 inner structs */

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        outerReference = outerArray + i;
        outerReference->innerStruct = malloc(10 * sizeof(*outerReference->innerStruct));
    }

    printf("address: '%s'\n", outerArray[3].innerStruct[4].address);

    strcpy(outerArray[3].innerStruct[4].address, "<emtpy>");

    printf("address: '%s'\n", outerArray[3].innerStruct[4].address);

    return 0;
}
```

The next time you post code please be so kind and make it compile.